# Get the differences from two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| country | coin |
| --- | --- |
| USA | coin1 |
| USA | coin2 |
| Mexico | coin3 |

Each coin is unique, and it can change the country. For example:

| country | coin |
| --- | --- |
| USA | coin1 |
| Mexico | coin2 |
| Mexico | coin3 |

What I'm trying to find is a way to see which lines have changed. My desired output:

| country | coin |
| --- | --- |
| Mexico | Coin2 |

Comment: have you tried pandas merge with an inner join

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `concat` to combine them, and then use `drop_duplicates` to get the difference. For example:

`concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

**EDIT:**

To get just the one row, you can get the negation of everything common between the two dataframes by turning applying `list` to them and using `.isin` to find commonalities.

`df1[~df1.apply(list,1).isin(df2.apply(list,1))]`

Comment: This will give 2 rows as both Mexico and USA are different for coin2. Also note `False` not `false`.

Comment: Saw that. Fixed the answer accordingly